# PHP and curl for fetching currency rate from Yahoo Finance

Tags: php, regex, curl, web-scraping

I wrote the following php snippet to fetch the currency conversion rate from Yahoo Finance.

I'm using curl to fetch the data.
Suppose, I want to convert from US dollars (USD) to Indian National Rupee (INR),then the url is http://in.finance.yahoo.com/currency/convert?amt=1&from=USD&to=INR&submit= and the Indian Rupee value is shown as 45.225.
However,if i run my code, the value im getting is 452.25. Why this discrepancy?

```
<?php

  $amount = $_GET['amount'];
  $from = $_GET['from'];
  $to = $_GET['to']; 
  $url = "http://in.finance.yahoo.com/currency/convert?amt=".$amount."&from=".$from."&to=".$to;
  $handle = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $data = curl_exec($handle);
  if(preg_match_all('/<td class="yfnc_tabledata1"><b>(?:[1-9]\d+|\d)(?:\.\d\d)?/',$data,$matches))
  {
    print_r($matches[0][1]);
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Not found !";
  }
  curl_close($handle);

?>
```

Is there something wrong with my regex?

Comment: Obligatory response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Finance (almost) certainly has a corresponding API, so you don't have to parse some random HTML for currency conversion.

Also, I would presume using something like Google's [http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=1 EUR IN USD](http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1%20EUR%20IN%20USD) and parsing this response is much more stable than parsing Yahoo's HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rates in XML or JSON format using yahoo.finance.xchange open table:

[Try it in YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%3D%22eurusd%2C%20usdinr%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)

Answer (score 1):

following code works. Give a try

```
$url = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?
Amount=1&From=USD&To=INR";

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
 "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = explode('uccResultAmount', $rawdata);
@$data = explode('uccToCurrencyCode', $data[1]);

$amount = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.]/', '', $data[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access Yahoo Currency via .csv files so it's much easier to parse those. Example: http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s='EURUSD'=x

And simple code:

```
function currencyImport($from,$to)
{
$url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s='. $from . $to .'=X';
$handle = @fopen($url, 'r');

if($handle)
{
    $result = fgets($handle, 4096);
    fclose($handle);
}

$currencyData = explode(',',$result);
return $currencyData[1];
}
```